# Bootstrap Modal

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have problem with bootstrap modal , i cant define a id on that modal to show some informations.

`<a href=\"#likes\" data-toggle=\"modal\">test</a>`

Other code

```
<div id="likes" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
   <h3 id="myModalLabel">People who like this</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
   <?php
   $quelike = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM likes WHERE statusid='$statusid'"));

   echo " <div class=\"modal-content\"> ".$quelike['firstname']." </a><br /> </div> <div class=\"spacelikes\"></div>";
   ?>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-footer">
   <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
   </div>
   </div>
```

I just need to set informations who liked post for for every post.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: In what way can't you define an id?

Comment: Like u can see i need to define statusid to get some informations to show on modal like firstname / lastname etc.. But problem is how to define a statusid on this modal?

Comment: Ah, I see. Where should status id come from?

Comment: As has been noted, your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Considering that the `mysql_` family of functions is being deprecated, there's no time like now to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Answer (score 3):

First off there may be an issue in your anchor:

```
<a href="#likes" data-toggle="modal">test</a>
```

Should be:

```
<a data-target="#likes" data-toggle="modal">test</a>
```

If you intend it to launch your modal.

As to actually passing in the statusId this depends. If statusId is the same over the course of a page then what you have should work (although as others have mentioned there is SQL injection vulnerabilities in your code and the mysql_ functions should no longer be used).

If status id can change during the course of the page (i.e. it can be set by javascript) then you probably should place the logic to grab the details in a new page and use this page in the modal:

```
<a href="page-which-takes-statusId.php" data-target="#likes" data-toggle="modal">test</a>
```

Which will load that page in the modal and show the info you require.

Comment: Thanks i solved one problem but now there is other problem.When i get informations for one post it show me infromations but if i wanna to see other post information it show me again same informations.

Comment: Jim. I saw this question and wanted to ask you: I have x rows in a table with a column that contains a link that shows the BS modal. How can i define a custom url to be called for each link after closing the modal? thanks